# Add a WHERE in COUNT(*) condition MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL Query which retrieve the average rating of rating table joined with a ads table.

My query works fine, But I want to add a WHERE statement to get only the ads which get two or more ratings.

This is my query:

```
SELECT ad_id, AVG(rating) as average_rating,
COUNT(user_id) as num_rates
FROM ads_rating
GROUP BY ad_id
```

And my desired query:

```
SELECT ad_id, AVG(rating) as average_rating,
COUNT(user_id) as num_rates
FROM ads_rating
WHERE num_rates > 1
GROUP BY ad_id
```

But MariaDB is telling me:
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'num_rates' in 'where clause'

Thanks and sorry my noob in MySQL

Comment: Consider using the **having** clause, which works with aggregated functions like COUNT

Comment: You should using `having` in your group statement.

Comment: having works with groupby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use column aliases in the WHERE 
So you need to do.

```
SELECT ad_id, AVG(rating) as average_rating,
COUNT(user_id) as num_rates
FROM ads_rating
WHERE COUNT(user_id) > 1
GROUP BY ad_id
```

Or better using HAVING works with the GROUP BY

```
SELECT ad_id, AVG(rating) as average_rating,
COUNT(user_id) as num_rates
FROM ads_rating
GROUP BY ad_id
HAVING COUNT(user_id) > 1
```

Comment: Wow, this is the answer (the second snippet), I can accept it until 8 minutes, but Thanks!